Differentiate between client file download pause and abort from a browser in a java server
I have a Java ServerSocket on an android sharing app that shares files over the network via the HTTP protocol.
I want to tell the user who uses the ServerSocket on his phone whether the other user using the browser clicked Abort or Pause.
At first I noticed that when client clicks pause it causes InputStream.read() of the socket to throw IOException with Broken pipe message.
So I did this.
try {
 // ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    if( "Broken pipe".equals(e.getMessage()) ) {
        progressManager.reportPaused();
    } else {
        progressManager.reportAbort();
    }
    Log.d(MY_LOGTAG, "SendFileResponse(). Exception: " + e.getMessage());

}

Testing the Abort button in browser it triggered progressManager.reportPaused();
And in logcat I noticed that it throw the same Broken pipe exception.
I want a way to make a pause call progressManager.reportPause() and an abort to call progressManager.reportAbort() if possible.
if not possible I wonder if there is a way to tell the browser that we don't support pausing and disable that pause button.

HTTP doesn't have pause functionality. It have ability to download files from specified offset. Browser probably use that feature to resume downloading.
